# XML preserve carriage return (CR) when loading XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, whitespace

I have the following XML file which contains carriage return characters (CR):

[image]

After loading the XDocument,

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(fileName, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

the (CR) characters are converted to carriage return, line feed characters (CR)(LF):

[image]

Is there a way to prevent those characters conversion?

Comment: Use XmlWriterSettings to save file :             XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.NewLineChars = "\r";

Comment: Could you please provide a complete code example?

Comment: Where doc is an XDocument :             XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.NewLineChars = "\r";
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("filename", settings);
            doc.Save(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();

Comment: I want to load an existing xml file...how can i do this?

Comment: XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Input Filename"). If you have a string XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

Comment: I have your suggested solution...the problem now is that all new line characters are converted to (CR) characters. I would like to preserve the initial (CR)(LF) characters...and also keep the initial (CR) characters...

Comment: White spaces are not required in xml and there is no good way of saving blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

The XML specification says that `\n`, `\r`, and `\r\n` are treated as equivalent, and are all normalized to `\n` by the XML parser. If you want a CR (`\r`) in your content that isn't going to be junked by the XML parser in this way, you have to write it as `&#x0D;`.

Comment: I have chanded the original xml file to this '<x id="1158"/>&#x0D;&#x0D;&#x0A; <mrk mtype="seg" ' but unfortunately the problem persists...thanks for your help

Comment: Then it might be something specific to XDocument, which I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Kay said, `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n` are treated as equivalent.

Therefore, if you need to have a separate `\r` character in the xml, then you must to write it as `&#x0D;` entity.

Let's create a test xml with the content we need.

```
string s = "<root><a/>&#x0D;\r\n<b/>&#x0D;<c/>\r\n</root>";

File.WriteAllText("test.xml", s, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Now let's read it with preserve whitespace characters and see what they are converted to.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

foreach (var node in doc.DescendantNodes())
{
    if (node is XElement elem)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Element: " + elem.Name);
    }
    if (node is XText text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Text: " + 
            string.Join(", ", text.Value.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("X"))));
    }
}
```

The result will be as follows.

```
Element: root
Element: a
Text: D, A
Element: b
Text: D
Element: c
Text: A
```

As you can see, whitespace characters are stored in `XText` nodes.

The `&#x0D;` entity is represented as the `\r` (`D` character in hexadecimal representation).

The newline `\r\n` is represented as a single character `\n` (`A` in hexadecimal representation).

Therefore, you can parse the contents of `XText` nodes and manually define their contents.

Comment: thanks for your help...I have updated the xml file to reflect the one you provide but I would like to pseserve \r character also when I save the xdocument....doc.Save("test.xml", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)...after saving the &#x0D; entity is vanished from the file

Comment: @tsiro - Well, I'll say, "No, you don't need this". Because it doesn't make sense. As already mentioned, `\r` and `\n` have the same equivalence. It's better to find out why the source XML has such strange formatting, where you get such symbols in it. And fix the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file in with a StreamReader, sending that into an XmlTextReader and loading that into the XDocument.  This should (hopefully) preserve your carriage returns.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(reader);
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
```

Comment: OP also wants to preserve whitespace characters when saving.

Comment: I just did a test with this and it is also preserving whitespace

Comment: This is the best solution although it should still have the `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace` to reduce even more change is this is important for diff compares.